# Distinguishing between “ne... que” vs. “ne (littéraire)... que”

Tags: grammaire, négation

Here's a sentence¹ that I stumbled over:

> On **ne** saurait en conclure (comme on l'a fait parfois) **que** l'achimie fut, par example, une sorte de religion à mystères: elle en emprunta simplement quelques apparences.

I initially read it as a “ne … que” sentence: “One would **only** be able to conclude…”. But I suppose it's actually a *ne* littéraire, and the *que* is just part of “conclure”: “One couldn't conclude (as some have sometimes done) that…”.

Is there a general rule for distinguishing between “ne … que” and «ne (littéraire) … que”?

–
<sup>1. *Le fixe et le volatile: Chimie et alchimie de Paracelse à Lavoisier* (Didier Kahn)</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, and [Nico Mezeret's rule of thumb](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/18571/7224) is actually the correct answer.

### Litterary form

This is the dated/litterary form of "*ne*" (actually "*ne … pas*" with "*pas*" being omitted), followed by a "*que*".

Thus, the (simplified) sentence

> On **ne** saurait en conclure **que** l'alchimie est une religion.

could be written

> On **ne** saurait **pas** en conclure **que** l'alchimie est une religion.

The real rule here is that the "*que*" is not related to "*ne*", it only serves as to introduce a subordinate clause (which as a consequence includes a **conjugated** verb).

Then, the translation uses **not**.

### Restrictive form

Some examples:

> *Je ne mange que de la viande.* (I only eat meat.)
> *Ce ne sont que des insectes.* (They're only bugs.)
> *Je ne fais que passer.* (Just passing through!)

The thing here is that there is **no conjugated verb** after *que*. Infinitive verbs and nouns (nominal groups, with sometimes a partitive as in our first example) are possible, not subordinate clauses.

As [BBBreiz](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/9976/bbbreiz) noted, the most generic translation for "*ne ... que*" would be "**nothing but**".

#### Trap form

As the asker noticed, if you remove "*pas*" before "*quoi*", "*quoi*" becomes "*que*". The translation however is not the same as in the first case. Let's have examples:

> *Je **ne** sais **pas quoi** faire.* > *Je **ne** sais **que** faire.* (I don't know **what** to do.)
> *On **ne** saurait **pas quoi** répondre.* > On **ne** saurait **que** répondre. (You wouldn't know **what** to do.)

Comment: The analyse by Mr.Chop is quite correct. I can add that the restrictive form "ne...que" is the equivalent of the English "nothing but" : a negative form followed by an exception.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of telling this and it slipped my mind while I was typing the rest.

Comment: I thought of a funny exception: sentences like «je ne sais que faire», «on ne saurait que répondre», etc, where the «que» just means "what".

Comment: Well, that's because it's a litterary (maybe not litterary, but heightened)  way to write "_Je ne sais **pas quoi** faire._" This is interesting enough to integrate in my answer, which I'll do right now.

Comment: Ah, cool, I wasn't aware of the "pas quoi" --> "que" rule. Good to know!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is a proper rule, but I suppose a way to distinguish between the two is by looking at what follows the 'que'.

If the que is there to introduce a subordinate clause, like in your example, then it is the ne littéraire.

If the que introduces a verb, a noun, an action etc (ie je ne mange que de la viande, je n'aime que dormir sur le dos), it is the classic ne...que

Comment: that's what you get when you change your examples halfway through :). Thanks, edited now